# PHP Read Line From Text File, Only Selected Line

Tags: php, html

I am trying to search a text file for a string, and then display only the one line that was found.  Would like to display the found line in a label box.  My PHP is really weak.  I got the following code working which will display the first line in the text area.  Below is the contents of the text file: test.txt

```
First line
Second Line
Third Line
Fourth Line
```

My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$myfile = fopen("test.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fgets($myfile);
fclose($myfile);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

This code returns   First Line   into the text area, so how can I return    First Line   to
text box, label?

Any pointer toward the right direction?

Thanks
Mitch

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read Specific Lines From Big File Fast with Low Memory Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72942218/read-specific-lines-from-big-file-fast-with-low-memory-usage)

Comment: My te xt file has First Line, Second Line, etc...  each on a separate line, not one long line as shown above........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want to continue `fgets($file)` in a loop, and checking if the search string is in the result, then when the search string is found, echo the line. Something like this maybe...

```
while ( $line = fgets( $myfile ) ) {
    if ( str_contains( $line, $search_string ) ) {
        echo $line;
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that `str_contains` is php 8 and up only. There are other methods for lower versions.

Also consider that perhaps a database would be better for this type of operation rather than using a flat file...

Comment: My flat file exists as part of another program that I cannot modify.  The flat text file contains a lot of valuable data that I need to display. New PHP user, learning.........

Comment: Thanks, dqhendricks.  I am now able to search the file and read only the line I want.  I will now ask another question, and on to the next lesson!   :>)

Comment: How do I show the question answered?  and close the question?

Comment: @MitchSavage I wonder if you could use another bit of code to enter the flat file data into a database before you start dealing with user page requests, even periodically if required using a cron job or something. anyways, glad I could help.